# R - trying to have the output for survdiff come out in my latex pdf file in Sweave

Tags: r, pdf, latex, sweave

I'm trying to have my survdiff print out in the pdf using R, Sweave, and latex.

I'm copying all the relevant code below, but this is the part I need to print out:

```
        N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
male=0 10        3     8.57     3.624      4.67
male=1 65       48    42.43     0.732      4.67

 Chisq= 4.7  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.0306
```

Here is the code that gets me almost where I want:

```
s.male <- survfit( Surv(futime, status)~ strata(male), shou3, conf.type="log-log")
plot(s.male, lty=c(1,3), xlab="Time", ylab="Survival Probability")
legend(30, 1.1, c("Female","Male") 
       , lty=c(1,3) )
sma <- print.data.frame(survdiff(Surv(futime, status) ~ male
         , data=shou3, rho=0))
sma2 <- print.data.frame(sma, digits = 2)

> sma2
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(futime, status) ~ male, data = shou3, 
    rho = 0)

        N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
male=0 10        3     8.57     3.624      4.67
male=1 65       48    42.43     0.732      4.67

 Chisq= 4.7  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.0306
```

Here is all I'm trying that isn't doing anything.

```
<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
latex(print(sma), file='', landscape=TRUE, round=1)
#latex(sma2, file = " ")
#latex(print.data.frame(sma2, cdec = 2, file=''))
#malesd <- survdiff(as.formula(sma$call$formula))
#latex(print(sma2, latex=TRUE, coefs=FALSE, file = " "))
#latex(sma2, file = " ")
 #     , cdec=c(0,0,2,2,2), na.blank=TRUE, booktabs=TRUE, table.env=FALSE, center="none", file="", title="")
@
```

I can't seem to get the (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V elements out of the object, and I can't get the Chisq line out, which I would like (I tried cbind/rbind). I'm using R Studio, it's an .rnw file.

Comment: Wouldn’t capture.output() have succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions. Neither is very elegant.

Here is some example data.

```
n <- 1000
set.seed(731)
age <- 50 + 12*rnorm(n)
label(age) <- "Age"
sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n,
          rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
cens <- 15*runif(n)
h <- .02*exp(.04*(age-50)+.8*(sex=='Female'))
dt <- -log(runif(n))/h
label(dt) <- 'Follow-up Time'
status <- ifelse(dt <= cens, 1, 0)
futime <- pmin(dt, cens)
# Check it out:
survfitObj <- survfit( Surv(futime, status)~ strata(sex), conf.type="log-log")
plot(survfitObj, lty=c(1,3), xlab="Time", ylab="Survival Probability")
survdiffObj <- survdiff(Surv(futime, status) ~ sex, rho=0)
```

---

Solution 1: Instead of trying to output the results in latex, just use the raw output:

```
<<results=verbatim, echo=FALSE>>=
survdiffObj
@
```

---

Solution 2: Make the table "by hand"

```
<<>>=
tabl <- data.frame(N = survdiffObj$n,
   Observed = survdiffObj$obs,
   Expected = survdiffObj$exp,
   col5 = (survdiffObj$obs - survdiffObj$exp)^2/survdiffObj$exp,
   col6 = (survdiffObj$obs - survdiffObj$exp)^2/diag(survdiffObj$var))
latex(tabl, file = TRUE)
@
```

This still needs to be formatted.